# option to creat folder in touchwiz gone

Tags: launcher, samsung-touchwiz

hi i have touchwiz installed on my android and i can create folders but when i flash a custom rom and install touchwiz from the app store the option to create folders in the app drawer is missing does anyone know why or how i could fix this? or recommend another launcher that allows me to create folders in app drawer thanks.
this is the launcher i was using from playstore

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.galaxy.s.launcher

Comment: do you mean folders on home screen?

Answer (score 1):

> does anyone know why

The launcher you installed is not actually Touchwiz. As the description in Google Play says, it's a third-party "Touchwiz-style" launcher, not affiliated with Samsung at all. You can't actually install the Touchwiz launcher on your custom ROM, because it depends on Samsung's proprietary libraries, which are only included in the stock ROM.

You just need to look for another launcher that supports the feature you like. We can't help you with that here, though, as this site only works with specific questions and answers, not app recommendations.